# Why cant I make the panel over draw the items

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to create a panel with a code and make it hide all the stuff on the screen but this happens
https://gyazo.com/9d5951fc49a0f7e8e1432bc16fbc245a

Red part is the panel. This is my code

```
Controls.Add(new Panel() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red, Location = new Point (13, 58)});
```

Comment: Did you look at the z-index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the panel is behind all other controls. Try this:

```
 var panel = new Panel() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red, Location = new Point (13, 58)};
    Controls.Add(panel);
    panel.BringToFront();
```